# How to Change Name of Ports for use with Libraries?

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-10-iot-core

I am looking to use Serial Modbus with my SBC running Windows 10 IoT Core. I am able to write through the serial port using RS-485 when using the SerialDevice class from the **Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication** library.

The serial ports on my SBC are not labelled COM1, COM2, etc. I had to find them using `devcon.exe stack *` command. My ports have the name PNP0501#1 and PNP0501#2 which I was able to use as the port name in SerialDevice and it works.

This code works for sending message through the serial port

```
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
            if (devices.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (devices[i].Id.Contains("PNP0501#2"))
                    {
                        GpioStatus = string.Format("Connecting... {0} found", devices[i].Id);
                        DeviceInformation deviceInfo = devices[i];
                        SerialDevice serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
                        serialDevice.BaudRate = 9600;
                        serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
                        serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.Two;
                        serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                        serialDevice.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

                        DataWriter data = new DataWriter(serialDevice.OutputStream);
                        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                        {
                            data.WriteString("Test message");
                            GpioStatus = string.Format("Message sent {0}", j);
                            await data.StoreAsync();
                            await Task.Delay(250);
                        }

                        data.DetachStream();
```

I am looking to use a Modbus library to make it easier to follow the Modbus protocol. I was looking into EasyModbusTCP but am open to any library that works with serial communication.

When I try to setup a modbus client with this library, it asks for a port name and I enter PNP0501#1 because that is the name of that port and it successfully worked for straight serial messaging. However, It throws an error every time saying that that name does not start with COM.

```
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("PNP0501#2");
            IModbusSerialMaster f = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(serialPort);
            byte slaveId = 1;
            ushort startAddress = 100;
            ushort[] registers = new ushort[] { 1, 2, 3 };

            f.WriteMultipleRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, registers);
```

**Is there any way to change the name of this device to use the COM name so it can work with this library? Is there any library that will take the full name of this device without the word COM. Any help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: No.  Mod Bus for security is now using TLS which is over ethernet to make local/remote connections and then sending over RS-485 to device.  The ehternet connection is using HTML and is a wrapper to communicate with device over RS-485.

Comment: I thought that NModbus supports RTU which can be sent through a COM port as well? The examples I see use "COM1" or an address for TCP.

Comment: @PaulF http://comfilewiki.co.kr/en/doku.php?id=comfilepi:modbus_with_nmodbus4:index does the examples in this guide using "COM1" not suggest the use of Serial Ports? Any other modbus library would be fine too. And yes. I have tried creating the serialport object, then doing serialPort.Open() and it gives me an error saying that the portname doesn't start with "COM". Then if I try to put COM1 or COM2 in there, it says that that port doesn't exist.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the SerialStream .net object that is created by the SerialPort object - nothing to do with the NModbus library. Looking at the source code, there does not appear to be a way to override that check : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/sys/system/io/ports/SerialStream.cs

Comment: To find out which com port are on you system you can use Device Manager and look at the com number of the serial ports.

Comment: @jdweng can't use device manager on windows 10 iot core. But I used devcon.exe stack * to find the IDs for the COM ports that I am using

Comment: @PaulF darn, okay thank you for looking into that

Comment: @BWhelan, as far as i know, the port name can not be modified in Windows IoT Core. The EasyModbusTCP library is not compatible with Serial Communication in UWP app, it only supports TCP/UDP protocol. If you want to use this library, you can download the source code, and change the SerialPort which in System.IO.Ports namespace to SerialDevice.